# Lemon Cucumbers Pollinating Pickling Cucumbers

Tags: pollination, cucumbers

This year I tried to grow two cucumbers. Lemon and Pickling cucumbers. However I am only seeing Lemon Cucumbers show up on all of the vines. Would cross pollination cause the other vines to grow Lemon Cucumbers? I am positive that I planted a row of both types of cucumbers. They are not that far apart and maybe that was a mistake on my part. Has anyone ever heard of this happening? How far apart should I be planting different type of cucumbers to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if they are cross pollinating, that would not cause the fruits you're getting this year to be all lemon cucumbers. If you saved your own seed from both types of plant last year and grew from those, then you might get either kind of fruits, because they do cross pollinate. If you bought the seeds this year and grew them, then the Pickling cucumbers weren't actually Pickling cucumbers...